# ¿Cómo puedo hacer peticiones o actualizaciones de un server usando Provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, content-provider

Saludos a toda la comunidad; acudo a su ayuda para buscar asesoria para poder obtener actualizaciones de un feed, cuando hago un posteo; en este caso, especificamente, tengo un codigo para una red social, donde usando Provider, quiero pasar a un widget, data tanto inicial como futura de los likes dados a un post. Al desplegarse el timeline de la app, cada post lee correctamente la cantidad de likes recibidos hasta ese instante, mi problema está en que si hago click en like a un post, logro subir la data al server (getStream), pero no se como actualizarla en el widget una vez subido ese like. Acá dejo los codigos:

Este es el widget que quiero actualizar:

```
class LikesCommentsShareIcons extends StatefulWidget {
  final Activity activity;

  const LikesCommentsShareIcons({Key key, this.activity}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _LikesCommentsShareIconsState createState() => _LikesCommentsShareIconsState();
}

class _LikesCommentsShareIconsState extends State<LikesCommentsShareIcons> {
  bool click = false;
  int likes;
  int comments;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final activityProvider = Provider.of<ActivityProvider>(context);
    int likes = activityProvider.likes;
    int comments = activityProvider.comments;

    Color color = click ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tomatoRed : Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
    return Consumer<ActivityProvider>(
        key: widget.key,
        builder: (context, notifier, _) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              ReactionCounters(
                activity: activityProvider.activity,
                color: color,
                likes: '$likes',
                comments: '$comments',
              ),
              const Divider(
                color: Colors.black54,
                height: 5,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () async {
                          if (click == false) {
                            click = true;
                            await FeedService.postReaction(context, kind: 'like', activityId: widget.activity.id);
                          } else if (click == true) {
                            click = false;
                            //TODO: [GOT-74] implement method for erase or revert the like reaction
                          }

                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        child: !click
                            ? FadeInDown(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                from: 1,
                                child: const Icon(
                                  CupertinoIcons.heart,
                                ),
                              )
                            : ElasticIn(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                //from: 5,
                                child: Icon(
                                  CupertinoIcons.heart_solid,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.tomatoRed,
                                ),
                              )),
                    GestureDetector(onTap: () {}, child: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.chat_bubble)),
                    const Icon(CupertinoIcons.paperplane),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              CommentList(
                comments: widget.activity.latestReactions['comment'],
                activityId: widget.activity.id,
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Asi tengo mi clase Provider, la cual importa un model llamado Activity:

```
class ActivityProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  Activity activity;
  int comments;
  int likes;
  int dislike;

  ActivityProvider(this.activity) {
    comments = activity.reactionCounts['comment'] ?? 0;
    likes = activity.reactionCounts['like'] ?? 0;
    dislike = activity.reactionCounts['dislike'] ?? 0;
  }

  Activity get activityProvider => this.activity;

  set activityProvider(Activity activityProvider) {
    activityProvider = activity;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Y lo implemento de esta forma:

```
class ActivityContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Activity activity;

  ActivityContainer({@required this.activity});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ActivityProvider>(create: (_) => new ActivityProvider(activity)),
      ],
      child: FeedsCardModel(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          ActivityContent(
            activity: activity,
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}

class ActivityContent extends StatelessWidget {
  final Activity activity;

  ActivityContent({@required this.activity});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final type = activity.type;
    //final subType = activity.subType;

    return SingleTextPostCard(
      activity: activity,
    );
  }
}
```

Agradezco tu ayuda para resolver esto y seguir aprendiendo sobre Flutter.

Comment: Normalmente en estos casos, se usa Streams, para que cuando se detecte un cambio en el servidor, este notifique a la aplicación y se cambie el estado. Si el servidor que estás usando es FireBase, no tendrás problemas para hacerlo. Puedes simplemente usar [StreamProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html) o [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html). En caso de no usar FireBase u otro servidor que te permita el uso de streams, lo tienes más complicado. Si tu servidor acepta escuchar streams, basta con usar al

Comment: hola @Manuel como estás? gracias por responder. El servidor que usa este proyecto es getStream.io, no se si lo conoces; estoy justamente tratando de ubicar en la documentacion del servidor si admite uso de streams; presumo que si. Realmente no soy muy diestro implementando StreamProvider o StreamBuilder pero lo voy a intentar.

Comment: Echándole un ojo al servidor, he visto que en su documentación: https://getstream.io/chat/docs/flutter-dart/?language=dart tiene soporte para Flutter. Además, incluyen una serie de packages que, deberían, facilitarte la vida en el desarrollo. También tienen en el GitHub, una aplicación de ejemplo: https://github.com/GetStream/flutter-samples. Lee la documentación, échale un un vistazo al ejemplo, y espero que lo logres.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7FjCWHmP9Y&list=PLrS57q8gZKG_6vUaHN8lJytqq4cVZKu2T

Creo que en ese vídeo, se explica lo que quieres hacer.